# Error while generating API keys

Tags: android

I have encountered a problem while generating API key for adding Google map in my application.
I used the following code.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\your_user_name\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

And the error which is shown by the cmd

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\your_user_name\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
         at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad<JavaKeyStor.java:650>
     at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad<javaKeyStore.java:55>
     at java.security.KeyStore.load<KeyStore.java.1214>
     at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands<KeyTool.java:789>
     at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run<KeyTool.java:340>
     at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main<KeyTool.java:333>
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just wirte following comand in command Prompt.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin>keytool.exe -V -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "Your debuge.keystore file path" -storepass android -keypass android
```

Comment: cmd showed "-V recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Comment: @maria , its working fine for me, please check your jdk and debuge.keystore file path.

Comment: Do you know any other way to get API keys for adding google map to my applicaton?